# Batch: Copying from computer to network drive

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, xcopy

I've written a batch file that will do some tests then copy the results to a network drive. This use to work fine for me but over the last few days I have noticed it doesn't work for me and other people have said it has never worked for them.

This is the section that I am calling to copy to M: which all computers on our network can see. The section is being called and the archived results folder is being created but nothing is being sent to the destination drive.

Can anybody see what I've done wrong?

```
:CopyResults
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH_ORIGINAL%
For /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%a-%%b-%%c)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ('time /t') do (set mytime=%%a%%b)

set source="target"
set Archive= "Archived Results\Test Results - %CLIENTCHOICE% %mydate% At %mytime% Using %BROWSEROPTION%"
set ScreenshotDestination= "Archived Results\Test Results - %CLIENTCHOICE% %mydate% At %mytime% Using %BROWSEROPTION%\Screenshots"
mkdir %Archive%
echo %Archive%
echo d | xcopy %source% %Archive% /k /e /d /y /h /i

rem copy screenshots
set screenshots="Screenshots"
echo d | xcopy %screenshots% %ScreenshotDestination% /k /e /d /y /h /i

%Archive%\site\index.html

rem copy accross to M:
set Destination= "M:\ProductTesting\AutomationResults\%CLIENTCHOICE%\%mydate% At %mytime% Using %BROWSEROPTION% Ran By %username%"
set ScreenshotDestination= "M:\ProductTesting\AutomationResults\%CLIENTCHOICE%\%mydate% At %mytime% Using %BROWSEROPTION%\Screenshots"
set source="target"
mkdir %Destination%
echo %Destination%
echo d | xcopy %source% %Destination% /k /e /d /y /h /i

rem copy screenshots
set screenshots="Screenshots"
echo d | xcopy %screenshots% %ScreenshotDestination% /k /e /d /y /h /i
GOTO Del
```

Comment: If you run it interactively, do you get an error message or anything? Also, does it run as your user, or a different user? Finally, does it run "elevated" (i.e. "Run as administrator" is checked or similar).

Comment: What does it print to the screen?